# HTC G2 crashes, comes back on falsely saying battery level is 0%

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, battery, htc-desire-z, crashes

Recently my G2 has started dying whenever I use it for more than 5 consecutive minutes. When I reboot it I need to plug into a power source or it will not reboot and it reports that I have 0% battery even though I actually may have 95% or more. Removing the battery does not help - only a 5-minute wait period - could it be some overheating issue? It does not feel warm to the touch.
If I leave it off for about 5 minutes and reboot it, it then correctly reports battery life. I have had this phone since September 2010.
I am running Gingerbread 2.3.4.
Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I'd try getting a replacement battery. For less than $20, you either locate your problem or have a spare battery.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the problem is in your battery more precisely in battery controller.

There are a few possible solutions:

- Try recalibrating your battery.
- Try removing /data/system/batterystats.bin.
- Put somebody's battery inside (if you know somebody with the same model) and look how phone works. If it works fine with somebody's battery then just buy new one.

Comment: Thanks for your response - how do I recalibrate the battery?

Comment: Also my /data folder is empty

Comment: http://myhtcdesire.com/tutorials/how-to-improve-your-battery-life-calibration-tutorial . There are some more tutorials in internet. All those tutorials propose to make a couple charge-wait-boot cycles. I had some issues with my pocketbook`s battery but I solved it by charging and resetting my device in random order :|.

Comment: Install JuicePlotter from latedroid.com to see what happens to your battery